# What is the right way to typecheck dependent lambda abstraction using 'bound'?

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus, dependent-type

I am implementing a simple dependently-typed language, similar to the one [described by Lennart Augustsson](http://augustss.blogspot.dk/2007/10/simpler-easier-in-recent-paper-simply.html), while also using [bound](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bound) to manage bindings.

When typechecking a dependent lambda term, such as `λt:* . λx:t . x`, I need to:

1. "Enter" the outer lambda binder, by instantiating `t` to *something*
2. Typecheck `λx:t . x`, yielding `∀x:t . t`
3. Pi-abstract the `t`, yielding `∀t:* . ∀x:t . t`

If lambda was non-dependent, I could get away with instantiating `t` with its *type* on step 1, since the type is all I need to know about the variable while typechecking on step 2.
But on step 3 I lack the information to decide which variables to abstract over.

I could introduce a fresh name supply and instantiate `t` with a `Bound.Name.Name` containing both the type and a unique name. But I thought that with `bound` I shouldn't need to generate fresh names.

Is there an alternative solution I'm missing?

Comment: Whatever you do, you'll need to maintain the distinctness of t. That's necessary if you're doing the Pi-abstraction (how will you abstract t if you can't see it distinctly?) but it's also needed to typecheck the body (t is a type, different from lots of other types). You can keep t de Bruijn, but then you need to be a bit more careful about how to work under its binder. I'd pick a fresh name, and indeed I'd cache the type with it. I'm interested to see alternative approaches.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We need some kind of context to keep track of the lambda arguments. However, we don't necessarily need to instantiate them, since `bound` gives us de Bruijn indices, and we can use those indices to index into the context.

Actually using the indices is a bit involved, though, because of the type-level machinery that reflects the size of the current scope (or in other words, the current depth in the expression) through the nesting of `Var`-s. It necessitates the use of polymorphic recursion or GADTs. It also prevents us from storing the context in a State monad (because the size and thus the type of the context changes as we recurse). I wonder though if we could use an indexed state monad; it'd be a fun experiment. But I digress.

The simplest solution is to represent the context as a function:

```
type TC  a = Either String a -- our checker monad
type Cxt a = a -> TC (Type a) -- the context
```

The `a` input is essentially a de Bruijn index, and we look up a type by applying the function to the index. We can define the empty context the following way:

```
emptyCxt :: Cxt a
emptyCxt = const $ Left "variable not in scope"
```

And we can extend the context:

```
consCxt :: Type a -> Cxt a -> Cxt (Var () a)
consCxt ty cxt (B ()) = pure (F <$> ty)
consCxt ty cxt (F a)  = (F <$>) <$> cxt a
```

The size of the context is encoded in the `Var` nesting. The increase in the size is apparent here in the return type.

Now we can write the type checker. The main point here is that we use `fromScope` and `toScope` to get under binders, and we carry along an appropriately extended `Cxt` (whose type lines up just perfectly).

```
data Term a
  = Var a
  | Star -- or alternatively, "Type", or "*"
  | Lam (Type a) (Scope () Term a)
  | Pi  (Type a) (Scope () Term a)
  | App (Type a) (Term a)  
  deriving (Show, Eq, Functor)

-- boilerplate omitted (Monad, Applicative, Eq1, Show1 instances)

-- reduce to normal form
rnf :: Term a -> Term a
rnf = ...

-- Note: IIRC "Simply easy" and Augustsson's post reduces to whnf
-- when type checking. I use here plain normal form, because it 
-- simplifies the presentation a bit and it also works fine.

-- We rely on Bound's alpha equality here, and also on the fact
-- that we keep types in normal form, so there's no need for
-- additional reduction. 
check :: Eq a => Cxt a -> Type a -> Term a -> TC ()
check cxt want t = do
  have <- infer cxt t
  when (want /= have) $ Left "type mismatch"

infer :: Eq a => Cxt a -> Term a -> TC (Type a)
infer cxt = \case
  Var a -> cxt a
  Star  -> pure Star -- "Type : Type" system for simplicity
  Lam ty t -> do
    check cxt Star ty
    let ty' = rnf ty
    Pi ty' . toScope <$> infer (consCxt ty' cxt) (fromScope t)
  Pi ty t -> do
    check cxt Star ty
    check (consCxt (rnf ty) cxt) Star (fromScope t)
    pure Star
  App f x -> 
    infer cxt f >>= \case
      Pi ty t -> do
        check cxt ty x
        pure $ rnf (instantiate1 x t)
      _ -> Left "can't apply non-function"
```

Here's [the working code containing](https://gist.github.com/AndrasKovacs/2b0fce538ca5e91b85a3) the above definitions. I hope I didn't mess it up too badly.